# Запуск war файла с помощью Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, install

С помощью maven собираю java проект. На этапе mvn install все проходит успешно и формируется war файл в локальном репозитории .m2. Если можно запустить его, то я не понимаю как это можно сделать непосредственно через tomcat (положила архив в папку webapss, а также в эту папку отправляла сформированную папку, в которой хранится war файл, но все безуспешно)

```
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ test_mongo ---
[INFO] Installing D:\test_mongo\target\test_mongo-0.0.1.war to C:\Users\Home\.m2\repository\ru\habrahabr\test_mongo\0.0.1\test_mongo-0.0.1.war
[INFO] Installing D:\test_mongo\pom.xml to C:\Users\Home\.m2\repository\ru\habrahabr\test_mongo\0.0.1\test_mongo-0.0.1.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.126 s
```

Answer (score 0):

Зайти в веб интерфейс http://localhost:8080/manager/html и там добавить war

Comment: Разместила, но всплывает ошибка "ОШИБКА - Приложение по контекстному пути [/test_mongo-0.0.1] не запустилось". При попытке запустить по локальной ссылке apache tomcat выходит на страницу ошибки "403 Access Denied". Возможно дело в том, что делаю под manager_gui